# Why does EF 6 ignore applied migrations if I move the Migrations folder?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

When I first ran `Enable-Migrations` in my project, it created a `Migrations` folder under the project root. Then, I moved the `Migrations` folder to under my `Data` folder, where the context and models etc. are. Then I corrected namespaces in both already applied migrations.

Then I tried a third migration with `Add-Migration IdToLong`, and I got an error saying:

> Unable to generate an explicit migration because the following
>   explicit migrations are pending: [201703061039495_Initial,
>   201703061159110_ContactRequest]. Apply the pending explicit migrations
>   before attempting to generate a new explicit migration.

The only reason I can think of is that EF has stored a relative path to the location of the connection string, and that path is now useless. I have seen several reports that EF shows the same message when unable to connect to the database.

This hidden storage/config for EF goes against the grain of where we are moving with EF Core, and I really hope this problem doesn't occur there.

To get to my question then, what changed or didn't change when I moved the `Migrations` so that EF could no longer see that I had already applied those migrations?

Comment: Have you tried added the line `MigrationsDirectory = @"Data\Migrations";` to the constructor of your `Configuration.cs` so that EF knows where the migrations live?

Comment: You can provide additional parameters for the `Add-Migration` command to point EF to the correct config location: `Add-Migration -configuration YourProject.Data.Migrations.Configuration -ProjectName YourProject.Data -StartUpProjectName YourProject.Data`. Here `YourProject.Data.Migrations.Configuration` is the location of the Configuration.cs file. Maybe this solves your problem.

Comment: EF does already know where the migrations live. It tells me I can't add a new one because the old ones are still pending, so it finds the old ones. I think it searches the project for a `Configuration.cs` and if it only finds one, uses that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you move migrations, you may have (probably) changed the namespace of the objects. This namespace is used as the default for the ContextKey column in the __MigrationHistory table. So now when EF checks which migrations have been applied it won't match the old ones.

If this is your issue, you can fix it a couple of ways:

1) Run a script to rename the context keys to match your new namespace:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[__MigrationHistory] 
   SET [ContextKey] = 'New_Namespace.Migrations.Configuration'
 WHERE [ContextKey] = 'Old_Namespace.Migrations.Configuration'
```

2) Hard code the old context key into the migration configuration constructor:

```
public Configuration()
{
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    ContextKey = "Old_Namespace.Migrations.Configuration";
}
```

Comment: I think you might just have hit the nail on the head. I'll check later and likely accept.